# Chaining (not composing) DSC Configurations

Tags: powershell, dsc, powershell-5.0

I have a DSC configuration that installs a bunch of prerequisites (included PowerShell 5 itself and several DSC packages via Install-Package).

I have a second DSC configuration that does the work of installing Windows Roles/Features, software, configuration, etc.

How can I schedule these in a chained manner? That is, I want my "Setup" Configuration to run after my "Prerequisites" Configuration has finished applying successfully?

I can't use DependsOn or Composite Resources, because some of the DSC packages that the "Setup" Configuration uses are actually installed during the "Prerequisites" Configuration...so if I tried to make a Composite Resource with DependsOn, it would error out trying to generate the mof file in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

DSC doesn't support phases but you could use partial configuration to solve your scenario if you control delivery of the DSC configuration. Have two partial configuration partial1 and partial2. Deploy only partial1 using publish-DScConfiguration in push mode. Then run Start-DscConfiguration -useExisting for DSC to apply the configuration. Check the status of the configuration using Get-DscConfigurationStatus cmdlet. If first partial configuration was applied successfully publish partial2 configuration and again use Start-DscConfiguration -useExisting to apply both the configurations. You can use pull mode as well to deliver configuration but you need to have a way to publish partial2 on pull server only when partial1 is successfully applied. More info on partial configuration can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/partialconfigs.  I would suggest file a uservoice request (https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell) for supporting phases in DSC as well.